# How can I apply a tag to every command in an Ansible tasks file?

Tags: ansible

The Ansible best-practices documentation has this example code:

```
---
# file: roles/common/tasks/main.yml

- name: be sure ntp is installed
  yum: name=ntp state=installed
  tags: ntp

- name: be sure ntp is configured
  template: src=ntp.conf.j2 dest=/etc/ntp.conf
  notify:
    - restart ntpd
  tags: ntp

- name: be sure ntpd is running and enabled
  service: name=ntpd state=running enabled=yes
  tags: ntp
```

I'm looking to avoid duplicating the `tags: ntp` line.  Is it possible for each of these instructions to inherit a tag?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could work with - block:

```
➜  ~ cat become.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  user: vagrant
  tasks:
   - block:
      - shell: whoami
        register: result

      - debug: var=result.stdout

      - name: become_root_user
        become: true
        become_user: root
        shell: whoami
        register: sudo_test_result

      - debug: var=sudo_test_result.stdout
     tags:
      - block1
   - block:
      - name: creating_new_app_user
        become: true
        become_user: root
        become_method: sudo
        user: name=app_user password=Bzs310di86b6E groups="adm,sudo" system=yes state=present

      - name: become_app_user
        become: true
        become_user: app_user
        become_method: sudo
        shell: whoami
        register: app_user_test_result

      - debug: var=app_user_test_result.stdout
     tags:
      - block2
```

~ ansible-playbook -i realtime-automation/hosts-slaves  become.yml  --tags "block1"

In your specific case:

```
---
- block:
    - name: be sure ntp is installed
      yum: name=ntp state=installed

    - name: be sure ntp is configured
      template: src=ntp.conf.j2 dest=/etc/ntp.conf
      notify:
        - restart ntpd

    - name: be sure ntpd is running and enabled
      service: name=ntpd state=running enabled=yes
  tags: ntp
```

Comment: Awesome!  Looks like this feature requires Ansible v2 btw.

Comment: Yes you need ansible 2.0 to use blocks.

Answer (score 8):

Before v2 this could be achieved assigning a tag to an 'include'

Move this task to a different file, say ntp.yml

```
---
# file: roles/common/tasks/ntp.yml

- name: be sure ntp is installed
  yum: name=ntp state=installed

- name: be sure ntp is configured
  template: src=ntp.conf.j2 dest=/etc/ntp.conf
  notify:
    - restart ntpd

- name: be sure ntpd is running and enabled
  service: name=ntpd state=running enabled=yes
```

And then include it in main.yml

```
---
# file: roles/common/tasks/main.yml
- include: ntp.yml
  tags: ntp
```

Comment: I see you've still included the `tags: ntp` in the ntp.yml file, but if I understand your answer correctly, those tags could be removed?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you don't need the `tags: ntp` in ntp.yml @Ryre